# Is it possible to process images in the camera view with flutter and official plugins?

Tags: flutter, image-processing, real-time

I'd like to process some images with firebase and based on the results print something over the image but instead of using an image from imagepicker I wanto do it while the camera is running live.

Is this possible using default plugins? I've been searching for hours but I've not able to find anything to interact frame per frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the official Camera plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Camera controller has a startImageStream method where you can listen to image stream and process frame by frame like this:

```
  controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
  controller.initialize().then((_) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    controller.startImageStream((CameraImage availableImage) {
       // process the frame here
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hello, I´ve spend some time trying to make it work but I´ve not been able to just display the frame before doing any processing. Can that CameraImage be treated as a plain image some how? I´ve not found a way of going from that clase to an Image class to display and the documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: @nck If you could give me more details of what exactly you want to do with the image, I might be able to assist you!

Comment: I want to use firebase text recognition in device to render something over the coordinates given by firebase when a text matches. And I would like to do this live while the camera is running. I have more or less all other pieces implemented if I just take a photo and process it. But I´m not able to do this with the live stream

Comment: @nck Here is an example of using Firebase ml kit for face recognition. It should be the same idea for the most part. https://github.com/dshukertjr/snow/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: @nck If you need more assistance with the code, if you could open another question and let me know in the comments here, I should be able to help you!

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for, the handling of those planes is not intuitive at all.